# Extracting specific data from multiple strings

Tags: python, string, loops

Been playing around with this. Haven't cleaned it up yet. It basically does what nslookup does. Takes a (or multiple) host name from a text file  and returns the corressponding IP address.

```
def getIPAddresses(file):
    emptyList = []
    someString = ".com"
    with open(file, "r+") as output:
        for line in output:
            emptyList.append(line)
            my_new_list = [x.strip() + someString for x in emptyList]
        return(my_new_list)


def lookup():
    try:
        while True:
            enterSomething = input("Enter something: ")
            if os.path.exists(enterSomething):
                for n in getIPAddresses(enterSomething): 
                    ip_info = socket.getaddrinfo(n, 80)
                    b = list(["nslookup of " + str(n) +"\n"]  + ip_info +(["\n" + "Result of " +str(n)]))
                    values = ''.join(str(v) for v in b)
                    abc = values+ "\n"
                    print()
                    print(abc)
                break
            elif not os.path.exists(enterSomething):
                print("No such file or directory " + str(enterSomething))       
    except(UnicodeError):
        print("")
```

So if I had a text file with the following:

```
www.google
www.espn
```

it would return

```
nslookup of www.google.com
(<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, 0, 0, '', ('172.217.1.68', 80))(<AddressFamily.AF_INET6: 23>, 0, 0, '', ('2607:f8b0:4006:808::2004', 80, 0, 0))
Result of www.google.com


nslookup of www.espn.com
(<AddressFamily.AF_INET: 2>, 0, 0, '', ('199.181.133.5', 80))
Result of www.espn.com
```

My question is that is there is a way I can extract only the corresponding ip addresses such as `172.217.1.68` and `2607:f8b0:4006:808::2004` for www.google.com and so on?

Comment: How about you print just the socket information instead of doing all that string concatenation?

Answer (score 0):

So your code returns a tuple, tuples can be indexed much like a list.

here's what I tested

```
google = socket.getaddrinfo('www.google.com', 80)
google[0][4]
returns ('74.125.141.104', 80)
```

thus to get the ip address associated
do

```
google[0][4][0]
```

to get

```
'74.125.141.104'
```